# Showing A is a open set.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying Real Analysis and having a hard time solving this question.

Let $A⊆\mathbb{R}$. Let $A^c$ denote the complement of $A$. Let $(A^c)′$ denote the set of all accumulation points of $A^c$. Show that $A$ is open if and only if $A ∩ (A^c)′ = ∅.$

$(A^c)′⊆A^c$, by definition. Also I have $A ∩ (A^c)′ = ∅$, which is given in the question.

How can I prove A is open? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: note that a set $B$ is closed if and only if $B' \subseteq B$.

Solution:

> $A\cap (A^c)' = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow (A^c)' \subseteq A^c \Leftrightarrow A^c \,\text{is closed}\; \Leftrightarrow\; A\, \text{is open}$

Comment: Thank you so much!